# Gridview Not Triggering Events

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to use the events on my Gridview control. But its not firing the events when expected. i.e, for `OnSelectedIndexChanged`, when changing the selected cell/row nothing happens. I've tried with `OnSelectedIndexChanged` as well as `OnRowUpdating`. The breakpoint is never hit in `gvQ15_RowUpdating`. I've even tried using the OnTextChanged event for the child textboxes or the gridview and they are not firing.

#### Markup

```
<asp:GridView AutoPostBack="true" ID="gvQ15" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Prescription Medication Name" ItemStyle-Width="25%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrescriptionMedicationName" runat="server" Width="100%" OnTextChanged="txtPrescriptionMedicationName_TextChanged" BordewWidth="0" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Originally Prescribed" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOriginallyPrescribed" runat="server" Style="min-width: 110px; width: 100%;" BorderWidth="0" OnTextChanged="txtDateOriginallyPrescribed_TextChanged" />
                <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="meetxtDateOriginallyPrescribed" runat="server" MaskType="date" UserDateFormat="MonthDayYear" Mask="99/99/9999" TargetControlID="txtDateOriginallyPrescribed" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Frequency and Dosage" ItemStyle-Width="25%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrequencyAndDosage" runat="server" Width="100%" BorderWidth="0" OnTextChanged="txtFrequencyAndDosage_TextChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Condition" ItemStyle-Width="25%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCondition" runat="server" Width="100%" BorderWidth="0" OnTextChanged="txtCondition_TextChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Onset Date" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtConditionOnsetDate" runat="server" style="min-width:110px;width:100%" BorderWidth="0" OnTextChanged="txtConditionOnsetDate_TextChanged" />
                <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeConditionOnsetDate" runat="server" MaskType="date" UserDateFormat="MonthDayYear" Mask="99/99/9999" TargetControlID="txtConditionOnsetDate" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

#### Code Behind

```
 Protected Sub gvQ15_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Session("Prescriptions") = gvQ15.DataSource
 End Sub
```

Comment: add `OnRowUpdating="gvQ15_RowUpdating"` event to your GridView.

Comment: @Asif.Ali I've tried that with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `CausesValidation="False"` attribute to your CommandField.

```
<asp:commandfield ShowEditButton="True" CausesValidation="False" HeaderText="Edit"/>
```

Or,

Add the `EnableViewState="True"` attribute to your GridView.

---

For TemplateField use this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Command">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button CommandName="Edit"   Text="Edit"   ID="btnEdit" Runat="server"></asp:Button>
        <asp:Button CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" ID="btnDel"  Runat="server"></asp:Button>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button CommandName="Update" Text="Update" ID="btnUpdate"  Runat="server"></asp:Button>
        <asp:Button CommandName="Cancel" Text="Delete" ID="btnCancel"  Runat="server"></asp:Button>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Where would I add the CommandField. See my update question for the full markup

Comment: That would change the design. Right now the grid is always editable.

Comment: How does EnableViewState help? I'm still getting a Nothing datasource on postback

Comment: set datasource in page_load `if(!IsPostBack){databinding}`

Comment: Don't thinks this is going to work for me. The data is already lost on page_load. I need to figure out how to get the event fired so I can add to the viewstate.